# Determine if an WooCommerce order contains order notes while using "woe_order_export_started" hook

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

The `woe_order_export_started` filter hook is related to a [plugin](https://docs.algolplus.com/algol_order_export/filters-orders/)

This code is used for exporting orders with total > 10

```php
add_filter( 'woe_order_export_started',  function ( $order_id ) { 
    $order = new WC_Order($order_id);
    return   ($order->get_total()  > 10.00) ? $order_id: false;
});
```

---

I am trying to create a php code to find out whether the order has order note or not, and to ignore the orders which has no order note.

I found out the code to get the order notes

```php
$args = array(
        'post_id'   => $order->id,
        'approve'   => 'approve',
        'type'      => 'order_note',
        'search'        => 'Order status changed from Pending Payment to Processing.',
    );
    // woocommerce hides such records by default
    remove_filter( 'comments_clauses', array( 'WC_Comments', 'exclude_order_comments' ), 10 );
    $notes = get_comments( $args );
    add_filter( 'comments_clauses', array( 'WC_Comments', 'exclude_order_comments' ), 10, 1 );
```

How to I implement this with the `woe_order_export_started` filter hook to determine if the order has order note or not.

Basically I want to avoid exporting the orders which has no order note. So it should return false if there is no order note.

Answer (score 1):

The following answer returns false if there are no order notes, while using the `woo_order_export_started` filter hook

```php
function filter_woe_order_export_started( $order_id ) {
    // Get order notes
    $notes = wc_get_order_notes( array(
        'order_id' => $order_id,
        'order_by' => 'date_created',
        'order' => 'ASC',
    ));
    
    // Notes is empty
    if ( empty( $notes ) ) {
        return false;
    }
    
    return $order_id;
}
add_filter( 'woe_order_export_started', 'filter_woe_order_export_started', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: Thanks  but it returns an error `Cannot redeclare filter_woe_order_export_started() (previously declared in C:\xampp\htdocs\wp1\wp-content\plugins\woo-order-export-lite\classes\core\class-wc-order-export-engine.php(345) : eval()'d code:1)`

Comment: That error is there because you already used that hook, you need to delete the previous code and overwrite with this one

Comment: but there is no other code https://imgur.com/a/g35L2Nb

Comment: If the error message says it is. The error is not with my answer but with how you apply it. 
I can't solve this by changing my answer, since my answer works.. it's up to you to apply the solution